# System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly when trying to debug with VSCode

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a .Net Core API that runs fine on my mac if I use dotnet run . However if I try to run and debug with VSCode, I get the following error:

dyld: loaded:  /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.4/System.Globalization.Native.dylib
Unhandled exception. System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'GraphQL, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I've verified that my project's .cproj and runtimeconfig.json are similar to other projects I normally debug with VSCode.

Given that it runs fine with the dotnet run command via the VSCode terminal, could there be something missing with my launch.json?

My Launch.json
[image: My Launch.json]

My Terminal with the error -> not very descriptive

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I missed that the build using the csproj (that VSCode uses) produces a dll with a slightly different name that when I build and run via the terminal. Changing the "program" path in the launch.json to the dll that is produced from the VSCode build action resulted in the smooth runs I am accustomed to. I only realized this by checking the latest files produced when a build with VSCode's task is ran.